# A6211 works fine alone, but when I merge two A6211s on the same PCB, there is a current leak

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, driver, led-driver

I need some help; I probably lack electronic knowledge here.

I got an [LED driver circuit from Allegro](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/demo-boards/a6211-evaluation-board.ashx.). It uses the [A6211](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/a6211-datasheet.ashx) IC.

First I tested it on a protoboard and it worked fine; I controlled two of these boards with a nood MCU ESP8266 and it worked fine.

Then I made a circuit board combining two drivers and a voltage regulator to provide 3.3 V for an Arduino nood MCU ESP8266 and it worked, but when setting one of the drivers to turn off I still got a current leakage of 7.3 mA that flowed through the LED board and the LED was on, drawing a very low current.

I probably missed something when I merged the two boards into one single PCB. If I use one single IC on the same board it works fine.

This is the merged schematic:

[image]

Front of PCB:

[image]

Back of PCB:

[image]

Can someone give me some help and tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: _"when setting one of the drivers to turn off I still got a current leakage of 7.3 mA"_ What happens if you set both drivers to turn off? Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Thanks for your time Bruce, when I set both drivers to turn off, they turn off. Unfortunately  I do not have an oscilloscope. What really intrigues me is that when the 2 drivers are in separate boards they work fine and when I combine 2 drivers in 1 board the problem appears.

Comment: Jjust bought one that connects to the PC, 2 ch 20 mhz, that I believe works for me. What I should look with the oscilloscope, the PWM signals from the Arduino right, and where to look from noise coming from the circuit? My intuition says that the signal from 1 IC is in some form reaching the IC 2 and drive a bit of current